Create new tables from existing tables to normalize database
I am trying to figure out the best way to create new tables with additional columns to normalize my database. I have to add a column for the primary key made from data within the original table example: (key + year: 1-24, 2-24...).
How could I make the new table also update data automatically when the original table is updated.
I'm not sure if I am going about this the right way?

you could use standard CREATE TABLE commands.  You can use AS SELECT .. FROM syntax, or you could ALTER TABLE an just add the column(s)

I second ALTER TABLE as Randy suggested. Add your columns. If you are normalizing, I highly suggest using an auto-increment numeric pk. Your constructed key + year field should not be the pk.  Then UPDATE table SET KeyYear = Key + year from table.

Ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. [ask] [Help] Why is this question post tagged (data) [tag:normalization] or [tag:database-normalization]? What do you think it has to do with either? PS Smart keys are generally a bad idea. If necessary use composite keys.

Here is an example of altering your existing table to add a numeric pk and a unique KeyYear field constructed from Key and Year values in the same table.
 CREATE TABLE YourTable 
(   [Key]   VARCHAR(25),
    Year    VARCHAR(4)
);

INSERT INTO YourTable ([Key], Year) VALUES
    ('1',  '24'),   ('2', '24'),    ('3',  '24');

SELECT * FROM YourTable;

ALTER TABLE YourTable ADD pkID INT IDENTITY
       CONSTRAINT PK_YourTable PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED;

ALTER TABLE YourTable  ADD KeyYear Varchar(30);  

UPDATE YourTable  SET KeyYear = [Key] + '-' + Year

ALTER TABLE YourTable  
ADD CONSTRAINT UC_KeyYear UNIQUE (KeyYear);  

SELECT * FROM YourTable;    

--this should work
INSERT INTO YourTable ([Key], Year, KeyYear) VALUES
    ('1',  '29', '1-29');

SELECT * FROM YourTable;      

--this should error
INSERT INTO YourTable ([Key], Year, KeyYear) VALUES
    ('1',  '24', '1-24');

fiddle



Key
Year
pkID
KeyYear




1
24
1
1-24


2
24
2
2-24


3
24
3
3-23



